# Which EC2 machine is recommended for running Pillow/openCV?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opencv, amazon-ec2, python-imaging-library

We are deploying an image module written in Python on an EC2 machine on AWS. Currently we are using a t2.Medium instance for testing purposes but we are looking to get it production ready. The module runs openCV and Pillow and does a lot of data transfer. I tried searching Google to learn what would be the best set of machine specifications to search for on AWS to optimise for Pillow and openCV but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: this is an opinion based question but [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) has all the different types and what they specialize in, sounds like you would probably need either computer or memory optimized

Comment: I know about this page but I don't know what are the specifications that matter the most in my case, should I have my machine be memory optimised or compute optimised, or both? Should I instead opt for an accelerated computing instance? I have no idea.